# Android browser rendering half width of html text

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have already disabled the CSS, deleted half of the HTML code, it looks like it is a bug with the Android browser. I'm using Android 4.2.2, built-in browser.

How it should render:

```
Text 1234567891011
```

How it is actually rendering:

```
Text 1234
567891011
```

I have double checked the page code and the CSS, disabled Javascript and CSS, and still get the same results.  I'm not sure if it is a browser issue or a code issue.

Page to check: http://lucrebem.com.br/blog/emp/66-o-que-vender

Screenshots, as requested:

[image]

[image]

**So far I have found this:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Those images are from a tutorial using Android 4.1.2, which means those older versions of Android have that issue with auto-fitting the pages.  Isn't there a way to configure the code itself to fit the page, instead of having to change Android settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Had to insert this in the HTML:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

What it does is controlling the viewport layout in mobile, this way the page can fit to screen without having to change Android settings.

As stated here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag